# SQL Performance using MAX on joined tabled

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2

I'd like your views on the the two SQL statements below as regards to performance and best practice.

```
select 
* 
from BcpSample1 
where dataloadid = (select MAX(id) from LoadControl_BcpSample1 where Status = 'completed')
```

And

```
 select 
 a.* 
 from CiaBcpSample1 a
 inner join (select ActiveDataLoadId = MAX(id) from LoadControl_BcpSample1 where Status = 'completed') as t
 on a.DataLoadId = t.ActiveDataLoadId
```

I tried the Query plan in SQL Server Studio but after 2 runs both are returning showing the same query plans.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "regards to performance and best practice." it depends on many things. What works well one time might not be the best the next. You have to test, measure the performance and then choose.

You say the plan generated by SQL Server is the same, so in this instance there shouldn't be any difference. Choose the query easiest to maintain and move on to the next problem.